# Can we detect a live image for perfoming augmented reality using Qualcomm QCAR sdk

Tags: augmented-reality

I want to detect an image of my hand(wrist) using QCAR sdk of Qualcomm so that then we can place a virtual object (e.g watch) on it. Is it possible to achieve this using Qualcomm sdk. Can we detect a live image of hand everytime using QCAR-sdk.

Answer (score 1):

No. QCAR can only reliably detect and track planar (i.e. flat) images, and the image needs to have certain characteristics, such as sufficient contrast and complexity. It can't track 3D surfaces, like your hand. You'd need to have the person hold the tracking target, or attach it to their hand (e.g. using a glove ).